# Manipulating Pins in MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to make an annotation for a map and I want to change the pin color and add a subtitle. Does anybody know how to achieve this? Here is what I have thus far:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D policestation1;
policestation1.latitude = 48.858822;
policestation1.longitude = 2.307463;
Maps2VC *annotation2 = [[Maps2VC alloc] initWithCoordinate:policestation1 title:@"Police Station"];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:(id)annotation2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the mapView:viewForAnnotation: function of MKMapViewDelegate

Do something like this to use a custom image:

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotationView"];
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapMarker.png"];

    return annView;

}
```

I don't think you can change the pin colour.